# Cannot find declaration to go to in Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I've made an app which makes use of sensors of a mobile phone. If I change the TextView back to *textView.setText* than the textView doesn't work, but when I change it back to *TextView.SetText* the *settext* part doesn't work.

this is my MainActivity.kt:

```
    var sm = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    var list = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    var se = object : SensorEventListener {
        override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {
        }

        override fun onSensorChanged(sensorEvent: SensorEvent?) {
            var values = sensorEvent?.values
            var x = values?.get(0)
            var y = values?.get(1)
            var z = values?.get(2)
            TextView.SetText("X=$x\nY=$y\nZ=$z")
        }
    }
    sm.registerListener(se,list.get(0), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
```

this is my activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView.TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I would appreciate any suggestions from the community. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please change the id of your TextView in your xml

```
android:id="@+id/textView.TextView"
```

The name is really wrong. Use something like "@+id/text_view"

After that I think in Kotlin you cant use `setText` or `SetText`.. Please instead of this use:

```
textView.text="X=$x\nY=$y\nZ=$z"
```

Comment: Thank you for reacting,
I've tried it now but now the .text doens't work.
Do you have any solution for this problem.
thank you in advance.
TextView.text="X=$x\nY=$y\nZ=$z"